# Firing key event ctrl + space on JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keyevent

I'm new to Java Swing.  I need to fire event <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> on `JTextArea`

I could figure and find only one key event fired.  Any directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `KeyEvent` inherits the method [`getModifiers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiers%28%29) from `InputEvent`.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is a modifier.

Comment: Not within fingertip reach.  To echo @Jeffrey [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: @EdwinSnts there is a [good website](http://www.google.com) for finding examples once you have the correct names. The first hit directs me to the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) which has sample code and documentation including the modifier keys (see the KeyEventDemo)